# Unordered List Not Showing Bullets

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have created several unordered lists on a staging site page and for whatever reason they are not showing the bullet points.

The sample page has two sections.
I added the unordered list content to each section for troubleshooting, but the top section is where I need the lists to properly format.
The list items on the first section is showing weird horizontal spacing and no bullet points.
The list items on the second second section seem to be properly aligned, but again, not showing bullet points.

I have tried creating a new class for the unordered lists on this page, and still no luck. I only added the class to some of the unordered lists while trying to troubleshoot.
I am at a loss and not sure what the issue is.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

CSS class I created for the unordered lists on this page trying to override any custom CSS that might be on the site that I do not know about.

```
    .wateringguide  ul {
    list-style: disc !important;
    padding: 10px 0 !important;
    padding-left: 20px !important;
    }

    .wateringguide ul li {
    list-style: disc !important;
    color: #555 !important;
    font-family: boreal,sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    line-height: 24px !important;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    margin-bottom: 1rem !important;
    }
```

Page content/HTML

```
    <h4 style="color: #1f4e79; text-align: left;">Signs of Plant Distress: 
   </h4>
    <ul>
    <li>Wilting can mean the plant is getting too little or too much water.  In order to tell the difference, check the soil.</li>
    <ul>
    <li>If the soil is wet, soggy, or smells foul, you have an overwatering issue.</li>
    <li>If the soil is dry at a depth of less than 2 inches, you may have an under watering issue.</li>
    </ul>
    <li>If leaves have a yellow tint to them, the plant may be taking in too much water.</li>
    <li>Leaf tips turn brown if the plant is getting too much water or too little water.</li>
    <ul>
    <li>Plants that are getting too much water may have soft and limp leaf tips.</li>
    <li>Plants that are not getting enough water may have crisp and dehydrated leaf tips.</li>
    <ul>
    </ul>

    <h4 style="color: #1f4e79; text-align: left;">How to Correct 
    Overwatering:</h4>
    Avoid watering until the soil dries out.  If the leaves are starting 
    to look at little brittle, mist the leaves as needed until the soil 
    dries out.


    <h4 style="color: #1f4e79; text-align: left;">Considerations for         
    Proper Watering:</h4>
    <ul class="wateringguide">
    <li>Established plants no longer need as much water and benefit from deep, infrequent watering to develop a deeper root system. Approximately one inch of water per week, including rain, should be sufficient.</li>
    <li>Ensure that mulch, compost, or rock around the base of a plant is no more than 3 inches deep so water can move through the ground, making it readily available for plant roots.</li>
    <li>The top surface may be dry while the subsurface contains appropriate moisture. Stick a screwdriver or probe into the soil. The plant has enough water if the screwdriver or probe has damp soil on it when it is removed from the soil.</li>
    </ul>
```

Page URL: https://rltstaging2stg.wpengine.com/test-page-with-tables/

Comment: We need a [mcve]. Post the relevant HTML

Comment: just add `ul { list-style: disc !important }`

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Please also read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: inspect it and see what rule is removing them. You use a CSS reset file that removes it.

Comment: Edited with minimal reproducible example.  Just adding ul { list-style: disc !important } does not work. I have tried numerous variations and resorted to posting a question for assistance.

Comment: The code you have given has bullet points on the unordered lists - try it yourself (best if you can make it in to a runnable snippet) so there is something else you are doing that removes them. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and ensure you give us just enough code so we can see the problem for ourselves. Also use your browser's devtools inspect facility to check where/who is removing the bullets.

Answer (score 3):

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: disc;
    padding: 10px 0 !important;
    padding-left: 20px !important;
    }
```

```html
<h4 style="color: #1f4e79; text-align: left;">Signs of Plant Distress: </h4>
<ul>
  <li>Wilting can mean the plant is getting too little or too much water. In order to tell the difference, check the soil.</li>
  <ul>
    <li>If the soil is wet, soggy, or smells foul, you have an overwatering issue.</li>
    <li>If the soil is dry at a depth of less than 2 inches, you may have an under watering issue.</li>
  </ul>
  <li>If leaves have a yellow tint to them, the plant may be taking in too much water.</li>
  <li>Leaf tips turn brown if the plant is getting too much water or too little water.</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Plants that are getting too much water may have soft and limp leaf tips.</li>
    <li>Plants that are not getting enough water may have crisp and dehydrated leaf tips.</li>
    <ul></ul>
    <h4 style="color: #1f4e79; text-align: left;">How to Correct Overwatering:</h4> Avoid watering until the soil dries out. If the leaves are starting to look at little brittle, mist the leaves as needed until the soil dries out. <h4 style="color: #1f4e79; text-align: left;">Considerations for Proper Watering:</h4>
    <ul class="wateringguide">
      <li>Established plants no longer need as much water and benefit from deep, infrequent watering to develop a deeper root system. Approximately one inch of water per week, including rain, should be sufficient.</li>
      <li>Ensure that mulch, compost, or rock around the base of a plant is no more than 3 inches deep so water can move through the ground, making it readily available for plant roots.</li>
      <li>The top surface may be dry while the subsurface contains appropriate moisture. Stick a screwdriver or probe into the soil. The plant has enough water if the screwdriver or probe has damp soil on it when it is removed from the soil.</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
<ul>
```

You did not close the  tag in the list in two different places
This was the first mistake
The parent class (.wateringguide) of the list was not correct
Or it may not be in the correct order
This was the second mistake